# strange behavior in react when submitting a form it submit and delete in the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that submit some data and i have item component that has a delete button that delete an item but when i submit something it submit and delete the item in the same time

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import './MessageForm.css';

class MessageForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            submitted: false
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const messageData = new FormData(event.target);
        await ApiClient.addMessage({
            license_plate: messageData.get('license'),
            body: messageData.get('body')
        });
        // console.log("submitted");
        // this.props.refreshList();
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="MessageForm">
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="license">License Plate</label>
                    <input id="license" name="license" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="body">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="body" name="body" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
};


export default MessageForm;
```

this is the item component

```js
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import SocailShare from './SocialShare.css'
import { FacebookShareButton, LinkedinShareButton,
  TwitterShareButton,
  TelegramShareButton,
  WhatsappShareButton,
  EmailShareButton,} from 'react-share';
import { FacebookIcon, EmailIcon,
  TwitterIcon,
  TelegramIcon,
  WhatsappIcon,
  LinkedinIcon,} from 'react-share';
  import {
    FacebookShareCount,
    PinterestShareCount,
    VKShareCount,
    OKShareCount,
    RedditShareCount,
    TumblrShareCount,
  } from 'react-share';
import './MessageItem.css';

export default ({ id, submission_date, license_plate, body, handleDelete }) => {
    var timePosted = moment(submission_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm');


    const onDelete = (id) => {
      handleDelete(id);
    }


    return (
        <li className="MessageItem">
            <span>Time: {timePosted} - </span>
            <span>To license: {license_plate} : </span>
            <span> {body} </span>
            <button onClick={onDelete(id)}>X</button>
            <div className="SocialShare">
            <FacebookShareButton  url="https://github.com/nygardk/react-share#readme" >
           <FacebookIcon size={30}/> 
           <FacebookShareCount url="https://github.com/nygardk/react-share#readme">
           {shareCount => (
    <span className="myShareCountWrapper">{shareCount}</span>
  )}
           </FacebookShareCount>
           </FacebookShareButton>
           <TwitterShareButton  url="https://github.com/nygardk/react-share#readme">
              <TwitterIcon size={30}/>
           </TwitterShareButton >
           <EmailShareButton  url="https://github.com/nygardk/react-share#readme">
             <EmailIcon size={30}/>
           </EmailShareButton>

            </div>

        </li>
    );
};
```

and this is the message list component that renders the message item

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './MessageList.css';
import MessageItem from './MessageItem';
import ApiClient from './apiClient'


class MessageList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    handleOnDelete = async (id) => {
      console.log(id + "deleted")
      await ApiClient.deleteMessage(id);
      this.props.refreshList();
    }
    render() {
        const {
            messages
        } = this.props;

        messages.sort(function(a,b){
            //the list will be ordered in descending date order (most recent first)
            return new Date(b.submission_date) - new Date(a.submission_date);
          });

        const $messages = messages.map((message) => <MessageItem handleDelete={this.handleOnDelete} key={message._id} {...message} />);

        return (
          <section className="MessageList">
            <h1>Message Board</h1>
             <ul>
                {$messages}
            </ul>
          </section>
        )
    }
}

export default MessageList;
```

and this is the app component where everything is rendered

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import './App.css';
import MessageForm from './MessageForm';
import MessageList from './MessageList';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        messages: []
      }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.refreshList();
  }

  refreshList = async () =>  {
    const messages = await ApiClient.getMessages();
    this.setState({
        messages
    })
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1>Hello License</h1>
            <p>Send your messages to a plate number easily!</p>
          </header>
          <MessageForm refreshList = {this.refreshList}/>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/api"  render ={props => <MessageList refreshList = {this.refreshList} messages={this.state.messages} {...props}/> }/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: "strange behavior in react when submitting a form it submit and delete in the same time" Doesnt describe your problem, can you edit the title to reflect the question and add more details about problem into body.

Answer (score 1):

in your item component, this line `<button onClick={onDelete(id)}>X</button>` is your problem.

What you are inadvertently saying is that when the DOM renders this component, it should call onDelete right away, and the `onClick` handler will refer to `void`. To avoid this, what you want is to pass in a function like so: `<button onClick={(id) => onDelete(id)}>X</button>`

Comment: I want to ask you one more question. when I delete the list does not rerender unless i refresh the page despite calling back the refreshlist  func